# Pycrete or Pycrete 2.0 Q Has there been any research for structures against radiation protection in space with Pycrete type material?

Tags: radiation, materials, shielding, research

Background on [Pykrete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pykrete):

> Pykrete is a frozen ice alloy, originally made of approximately 14 percent sawdust or some other form of wood pulp (such as paper) and 86 percent ice by weight (6 to 1 by weight). During World War II, Geoffrey Pyke proposed it as a candidate material for a supersized aircraft carrier for the British Royal Navy. Pykrete features unusual properties, including a relatively slow melting rate due to its low thermal conductivity, as well as a vastly improved strength and toughness compared to ordinary ice. These physical properties can make the material comparable to concrete, as long as the material is kept frozen.

---

Liquid H2O is used for radiation shielding and [What thickness/depth of water would be required to provide radiation shielding in Earth orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/1336/12102) addresses that, but no one responded to the solid H2O Q part of the question.

Is the crystallized structure of 'ice' better/less-than than that of liquid? I would like to know if some material like Pycrete, material from 'living off the land mentality', has been researched for the purpose of space exploration/living/traveling ... ?

Comment: Interesting question! I added a litte background for those unfamilliar with Pycrete. At first I thought it might be a Python package ;-)